# Alternative to os.path.join in python to group png files in one variable

Tags: python

I need to find an alternative to using the `sys` and `os` module in python. I have a game that i developed in `pygame` that uses images for different sprites. Some sprites have numerous `.png` 's that are used by a function to create an animation effect. When using e.g `ship = os.path.join()` to link multiple `.png`s, after converting to an `.exe` (auto pytoexe) the `.py` file always gives me a fatal error and i'm pretty sure its because it can't find the images.

My game works perfectly in pycharm thought.

I'ved tried making the directories strings but obviously one variable can store multiple .png's. I also tried using a function provided by a user on stackflow but it still gave me fatal error when running the exe. The code shows how muliple .pngs with names of rocket1, rocket2, rocket3, ect from the local folder i made called sprites, are taken by the variable. But my game doesnt work when in exe and the png folders are put next to the exe.

```
missile_image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Sprites', 'rocket')
```

I need an alternative that can allow a variable to behave the same as with using the os module, but the directory stored can local to the py/exe file so the game can run once converted

Comment: Obviously you have problem with the location of the png files due to conversion to exe, not because using os.path.join(). How do you convert your game to exe? e.g. for pyinstaller read https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: You realize that here the os module just constructs the path *from the information you provide*? If the output is not suitable, the input is wrong. Focus your attention on whether ‚__file__‘ contains the information you expect, not whether a trivial, well-tested library call works correctly.

Comment: @buran okay i am using pyinstaller to convert my .py file, i read the article but i'm still a little confused on how to fix the issue. How i do i test if frozen or script

Comment: @Joshua, do you bundle them in one file or you just put them in a subfolder e.g. `path-to-exe/Sprites`? In any case in the article there is example script (at the bottom) that checks if frozen or not and print respective paths...

Comment: @buran, its in a subfolder called sprites, and whenever i open my exe a console window always pops up and disappears really quickly i filmed in slowmotion the console and apprently it says it can't find the module numpy therefore failed to execute exe. I use numpy for some parts of my game.

Comment: @buran thankyou for the help with understanding the os module, but apparently numpy is missing and that's why it isn't running correctly in exe, i don't understand why though?.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information provided in the comments, that OP is using pyinstaller.

Here is the reference to [respective section of documentation](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)
There is example script provided that test is frozen or not and print respective paths.

For convenience here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os
frozen = 'not'
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # we are running in a bundle
        frozen = 'ever so'
        bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
        # we are running in a normal Python environment
        bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print( 'we are',frozen,'frozen')
print( 'bundle dir is', bundle_dir )
print( 'sys.argv[0] is', sys.argv[0] )
print( 'sys.executable is', sys.executable )
print( 'os.getcwd is', os.getcwd() )
```

run it as py file and also converted to exe with the same options (i.e. one file or one folder) and run it again. This will help you to understand the difference in the paths used.

Comment: Apparently numpy is missing and that's why it isn't running correctly in exe, i don't understand why though?

Comment: read https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules add numpy explicitly as  hidden import